# In poisson distribution why does setting r = mean_value not output 50%?

Tags: poisson-distribution, discrete-distributions

If I want to find probability of 10 cars passing highway checkpoint in 60 seconds where on average 10 cars pass in 60 seconds.

Assuming there is no rush hour I can use Poisson distribution

[image: P(X=r) = e^(-l)l^r]

So lambda = 10 and x = 10, outputting P(X=10) = 0.125 => 12.5%

The answer is not intuitive since on average 10cars pass by in 60 seconds so shouldn't the formula output 50% when inputting x = 10?

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Comment: The average age of a human alive right now is 29 years old, but not half of all humans are 29 years old. These are very different things. Can you describe to us what you believe "average" means?

Comment: "on average 10 cars pass in 60 seconds"  means if I take 100 samples, sum number of cars passed and divide by 100 I would get 10.

Comment: Sometimes 9 cars pass, sometimes 11 cars pass, on rare occasions 20 cars may pass, so the chances that exactly 10 cars pass in 60 seconds is not that common.

Comment: This is the probability of getting *exactly* $x$ cars, not the probability of getting more than $x$ or less than $x$.  The sum of $P(x)$ for $x=0,\dots,10$ will be close to 50%: specifically, 58% (The sum from 0 to 9 is 45%)

Comment: Now I understand, thanks!